If you don't need any more buildings and buildings never get damaged, would you need to build more?
The title, basically.
There doesn't seem to be a need to make more buildings, and since they never get damaged, they won't need to be replaced, so would it be reasonable to build more buildings or not, and why?
Important(?):

This is pretty short term, around 250 years.
While you might need new buildings for new tech, that doesn't happen too often.
EDIT: Forgot to mention that the population does not grow.

Also, let me know if I can improve this question :)

As it stands, the question is something of a tautology.  "There isn't a need to make more buildings, is there a need to make more buildings?"

@jdunlop That's interesting, I didn't think of that, thanks!

For a real-life example of a similar situation, consider that metals such as steel and aluminum are recycled in a large proportion, dramatically reducing the need for new steel and new aluminum. Almost all the aluminum ever made is still in use.

This seems far too wide open. For instance, are we talking a city or a country or the entire world? And what time period are we talking, such as ancient history or medieval times or modern times or futuristic? And what's the economy like? Even if the population isn't growing, changing distribution of wealth can impact things. These and other unspecified factors could significantly influence any answer.

The question appears to answer itself, simplistically put you've asked would we need to build new houses if we don't need to build new house'.. well no, if we don't need to we don't need to do we [shrugs].. did you mean to ask something other than what you have? Perhaps "will we if we don't need to?" probably yes, we do a lot of things just for the hell of it,  but that's not what you've asked.

So these buildings don't need maintenance? Ie they don't rot, Or are they indestructible ie not damaged by flooding, fires, nuclear weapons etc?

@value1 "That's interesting, I didn't think of that, thanks!" and yet you still haven't edited it so that it isn't a nonsense

There is a major issue with the question. It is clearly written and the topic is clear - the problem is that there's a stark lack of primary logic applied in its writing. Please review what you've written and make it much clearer what it is you actually want to know.

For future reference, if ever you're again tempted to use the phrase, "the title, basically," you should realize that your question is a bad question. We can't read your mind. We don't know the circumstances of your society, how it got to the state it's in, why you need a particular condition to be true... nothing. The phrase is a hallmark of a lack of preparedness, which is why you have such a dismal question score. As for how to improve your question, please consider using the Sandbox.

Greetings! It's not often we see a query that is so heavily down voted and in the process of being closed! Unfortunately, people have been giving you answers, which means you can no longer improve your question or make it better. For your future reference, this forum really thrives on a specific kind of questioning: the Stack Exchange model, in contradistinction to other Q&A places, seeks narrowly focused queries, those that focus on a single worldbuilding problem. At the most charitable, yours is a question of people's wants and desires --- what people might (cont)

(cont) choose to do or what they might wish to do are simply not questions of worldbuilding. They are questions of character motive, action, plot or narrative. As such, and even if you gave us sufficient details in order to provide an answer, I'd still have to vote to close your question for being off topic. Check out our Sandbox which is a good resource designed to help your write good WB.SE questions!

@elemtilas Thanks, I'll make sure to use the Sandbox next time I have a question.

I'm proposing a Frame Challenge because this question fails to review the history of buildings. It only assumes the one-dimensional belief that buildings are constructed due to wear or population growth.
The world is full of abandoned buildings. Some are abandoned due to age, but some are abandoned due to the obsolescence of their purpose. What value a building constructed 200 years ago if its configuration and infrastructure no longer meet the needs of today's purposes? A perfectly good house today can be a whomping pain to live in simply because it was built in the days when only 1-2 electrical outlets were expected to be needed in a room and those outlets have only two prongs (U.S.) rather than today's three. I have a friend who lives in a house that's a problem because when it was built the owners needed only a 50-amp service with two fuses (branch lines)... for the whole house.
The only reason why no new buildings ever need be built is because nothing changes. Nothing. Ever. No technological advancement. No new purposes. No new projects. No innovation. No new problems to solve. Not a single new person added to the population. Nothing.
Unrealistic...
There's always a reason to replace the old with the new. Changes in safety protocols, changes in necessary production (did an earthquake happen? a war? a plague? a drought?), changes in technology, changes in resource availability, changes in transportation....
With one theoretical exception: technology is so advanced that it's Clarkean Magic, allowing buildings to reconfigure for whatever purpose they're put to. Maybe, maybe under that circumstance where we redefine what "new buildings" means it's possible to say that no new buildings need ever be built.
Maybe.
Better hope your society's needs can always be miniaturized or that no one ever needs more of anything. And you'd better hope your society's economy never becomes dependent on recycling anything (aka building new buildings) to sustain itself. I suspect no modern economy today can boast that.

There is only one correct answer to this question as it has been asked, and that's the trivial one of no .. "If you don't need to do you need to?" no is the only possible answer and the only correct answer.

@Pelinore That's a false answer. There is always a need to build or rebuild. I'll identify this answer as a frame challenge.

No, it's the only correct answer to the question as asked.. and a frame challenge requires a frame to challenge, which you do not have, the question makes a flat statement of fact "You don't need any more buildings" there is no frame of reasons for why you don't around that statement to be challenged, it just is.. first assuming the frame that wasn't given so that you can then challenge it?  that goes a little above and beyond the scope of a legitimate frame challenge in my book

As comments have pointed out, it depends on exactly what is encompassed by the word need (I need to breathe, I need vegetarian food, and I need to work, but the consequences if I don’t do those three things are very different!), but below are some ideas.
Fashion - you want to live / work in a building in the latest architectural style, so the well-off build a new house ever decade or two.
Prestige - since buildings last forever, having a building named after you is very prestigious. Before the current era these new buildings were actually useful, but now they sit as empty vanity projects.
Religion/ Superstitions - it is considered sacrilegious/ unlucky to live in a house in which a person has lived / died in, so every generation builds a new home.
Religion / culture is always an easy cheat with a question like this - maybe in order to propose marriage a young person must build a house for their mate - maybe the gods demand a new home be constructed for them every year, etc.

There is only one correct answer to this question as it has been asked, and that's the trivial one of no .. "If you don't need to do you need to?" no is the only possible answer and the only correct answer.

Increases or changes in Tech Level
Whilst a building may be able to be retrofitted with newer tech, if we look at Factories from the start of the Industrial revolution (for example) to the end of the industrial revolution.
Bigger Steam engines could drive more or bigger machines, which means bigger goods could be produced - which required bigger factories.
Fast forward to today and compare the early industrial factories to say the size of Boeing Everett Factory.
In addition, as tech increases and we can do more things in bulk, the size of the machinery gets bigger.
Just consider the size of a Tractor in the 1940s to the size of a commercial tractor today - if you build bigger things, you are going to need a bigger place to build them.
Therefore - if the region experiences a significant shift in Tech Level, then we would expect to see more buildings built to accomodate the increase in Tech.

There is only one correct answer to this question as it has been asked, and that's the trivial one of no .. "If you don't need to do you need to?" no is the only possible answer and the only correct answer.
